# TouchableOpacity is not working in all android device properly. In Some devices working fine React Native 0.73.2

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, touchableopacity

TouchableOpacity is not working in all android device properly. In Some devices working fine React Native 0.73.2

Imported from react-native

In some devices it is working fine but in some android devices it is not taking in one time after pressing on 2-3 times it works

react-native 0.73.2
touchableOpacity from react-native